# This special math expression with markdown in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown, symbolic-math

I need your help, please...
I want to show this kind of math expression with markdown on Jupyter [math](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIOQw.png), I found an example from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics.

here's the code:

```
\[ f(n) =
  \begin{cases}
    n/2       & \quad \text{if } n \text{ is even}\\
    -(n+1)/2  & \quad \text{if } n \text{ is odd}
  \end{cases}
\]
```

unfortunately, when I tried ran it with jupyter notebook markdown, I got this result: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT8gJ.png)
As you can see the "f(n)=" laying on the top-left corner and separated bit far from the curly-brace(centered-alignment), How can I put the "f(n)=", exactly the same as the first picture?

Note: 
I had tried putting this magic symbol "%%latex" on the first line of the code, it works, but I want to show only the math expression, not the code itself.

Comment: Math mode is started with $ or $$ in Markdown (at least, Jupyter's Markdown), not \\[

Comment: @darthbith,  Hi, thank you for the clue, I will add $$ at the beginning and ending, Sorry for this silly question